# Parse Volume Status of RSTCLI using Powershell

Tags: powershell, intel, hyper-v

I'm trying to parse output from rstcli64 (Intel Rapid Storage Technology Command Line Interface) with powershell for use with Hyper-v 2012 bare metal server. The goal is to find any volumes or disks with a status that is not "normal" by returning $true for 'OK' or $false for anything other than normal or $null. The ultimate goal to is to create an alert for Icinga. When it's all done I'll be posting the working script. Here's where I'm at, and I may be going about this in completely the wrong way:

I start with rstcli64:

```
rstcli64 --information --volume
```

Which outputs:

```
--VOLUME INFORMATION--

Name:              Volume0
Raid Level:        10
Size:              466 GB
StripeSize:        64 KB
Num Disks:         4
State:             Normal
System:            True
Initialized:       False
Cache Policy:      Off

--DISKS IN VOLUME: Volume0 --

ID:                0-0-0-0
Type:              Disk
Disk Type:         SATA
State:             Normal
Size:              233 GB
Free Size:         0 GB
System Disk:       False
Usage:             Array member
Serial Number:     WD-WCAT1F483065
Model:             WDC WD2502ABYS-18B7A0                   

ID:                0-1-0-0
Type:              Disk
Disk Type:         SATA
State:             Normal
Size:              233 GB
Free Size:         0 GB
System Disk:       False
Usage:             Array member
Serial Number:     WD-WCAT1F468139
Model:             WDC WD2502ABYS-18B7A0                   

ID:                0-2-0-0
Type:              Disk
Disk Type:         SATA
State:             Normal
Size:              233 GB
Free Size:         0 GB
System Disk:       False
Usage:             Array member
Serial Number:     WD-WCAT1H077856
Model:             WDC WD2502ABYS-18B7A0                   

ID:                0-3-0-0
Type:              Disk
Disk Type:         SATA
State:             Normal
Size:              233 GB
Free Size:         0 GB
System Disk:       False
Usage:             Array member
Serial Number:     WD-WCAT1F522503
Model:             WDC WD2502ABYS-18B7A0                   


rstcli64 : 
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

0
```

I'm interested in anywhere the 'State:' entry exits so I filter that out with Select-String, which I'm using like this, with this output:

```
rstcli64 --information --volume 2> Out-Null | select-string -Pattern "State:"

State:             Normal
State:             Normal
State:             Normal
State:             Normal
State:             Normal
```

... and this is about as far as I've gotten. I need to find out how return $true if all of the "State:" fields -eq "Normal", and $false if either there is no output ($null I assume) or if there is *any* "State:" -ne "Normal".

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

EDIT: Thanks for the help! This is what I ended up using TheMadTechnician's logic in: http://baremetalwaveform.com/?p=311

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well that's easy enough to do from where you're at. Run a RegEx match or run a -like and see if there are any that -match or -like and look for 'Normal'. Get a count, if the total number of Status -gt 0 and that count -eq the matched count then you're all set.

```
$Status = rstcli64 --information --volume 2> Out-Null | select-string -Pattern "State:"
If(($status.count -gt 0) -and ($status.count -eq ($status|Where{$_ -match "Normal"}).count)){
    "All is well"
}else{
    "Stuff be broke!"
}
```

Comment: This is excellent thank you! I found that the output of select-string needed to be split up on the carriage return so I came up with this and found it working very well $state = rstcli64 --information --volume 2> Out-Null | select-string -Pattern "State:"

If (
   ( ($state -split "`r").count -gt 0) -and ( ($state -split "`r").count -eq ( ($state -split "`r") | Where {$_ -match "Normal"} ).count) )
    {
    #OK
    $status = 0
    }

else
    {
    #CRITICAL
    $status = 2
    }

$status

Answer (score 1):

Another approach that will capture the counts of the states

```
$states = rstcli64 --information --volume 2> Out-Null | select-string -Pattern "State:"
$notNormalStates = $states | Select-String -Pattern "Normal" -NotMatch
if ($state.Count -gt 0 -and $notNormalStates.Count -eq 0){
    Write-Host "Everything Ok"
} Else {
    Write-Host "Something Wrong"
}
```

You could pipe the results of `Select-String` into `Select-String` again and spit out result that dont have "Normal". If you were just interested in the non normal state count you could use either of the following.

```
$notNormalCount = (rstcli64 --information --volume 2> Out-Null | select-string -Pattern "State:" | Select-String -Pattern "Normal" -NotMatch).Count
```

Also you could regex to just have one `Select-String` cmdlet

```
$notNormalCount = (rstcli64 --information --volume 2> Out-Null | Select-String -Pattern "State:\s+(?!.*Normal).*").Count
```

The regex would match "State:" followed by any whitespace followed by anything as long as its not "Normal" using a Negative Lookahead. Its worth noting that Regex is better designed to "match" things than to "not match" things.

Comment: I didn't go that route because he said that he both wanted to check if there were no output, or if there were any non-normal status states. Other than that, it's a nice one-line solution, even if it is kind of long.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician I attempted to save my answer

Comment: Yep, that answers his question now. Nice recovery. Hm, looks a lot like my answer now, you just pre-calculate the whole non-normal state count before the If/Then statement. You do it differently than I do though, using Select-String instead of Where -match, so it's definitely a different answer!